# Understanding Switch statement with "&" sign

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I'm designing a custom keyboard for Android. I used a sample SoftKeyboard project. In [LatinKeyboard.java](https://github.com/billymoon/javascript-android-keyboard-boilerplate/blob/master/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/LatinKeyboard.java) class there is a switch statement like bellow:

```
switch (options & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION))
{
    //Cases     
}
```

I'm trying to understand this switch statement. I searched switch statement documentation but I couldn't find "&" sign in switch. I also searched on other places for solution but no solution so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `&` is [bitwise operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm) which performs AND operation on provided value while `|` is bitwise OR operator which is performing OR operation on the values.

- `&` Bitwise `AND`
- `|` Bitwise `OR`

As explained in the link

```
 int a = 60;    /* 60 = 0011 1100 */  /*Binary*/
 int b = 13;    /* 13 = 0000 1101 */
 int c = 0;

 c = a & b;     /* 12 = 0000 1100 */ 

 c = a | b;     /* 61 = 0011 1101 */
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. Now I understood. But how I can recognize the outcome of the switch statement?

Comment: Well that completely depends on the `options`  as I think other two  variables are constants.

Answer (score 3):

The `&` has nothing to do with the `switch` statement; it's simply the [Java bitwise AND operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1). It does a bitwise "and" of the current value of `options` with the (constant) `int`-valued expression `(EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)`. (The `|` in that expression is the bit-wise OR operator.) The result is an `int` value that is then used by the `switch`. It's the same thing as writing:

```
int value = options & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
switch (value)
{
    //Cases     
}
```

except you avoid the need for a variable.